# Cannot See NonOrganic Installs in AppsFlyer Dashboard

Tags: ios, xcode, appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I have installed iOS AppsFlyer SDK, and I am able to see organic installs but I am not able to see NonOrganic installs, when I tried their "Simulate non-organic install" test. I still got an organic install. Is there something I need to do?

Comment: Try this link: https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-flutter-plugin/issues/25